# Create array with increased value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have on page some elements with id`s with number of row in the end. For example

```
<input type="hidden" name="productid1" id="productid1" value="4941">
<input type="hidden" name="qty1" id="qty1" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="productid2" id="productid2" value="4942">
<input type="hidden" name="qty2" id="qty2" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="productid3" id="productid3" value="4941">
<input type="hidden" name="qty3" id="qty3" value="5">
```

i know elements count, and i`m need make js array with key from productidX value, and value sum of values qtyX

i tryed like that

```
var out = [];
var tot = jQuery('#totitems').val();

    for(var i = 1; i <= tot; i++)
    {
        out[jQuery('#productid'+i).val()] += parseFloat(jQuery('#devQty'+i).val())
    }
```

but this is not working(

i`m need somesing like taht

```
[4931] => 7
[4942] => 1
```

can someone say me right way for this?

sorry for mistakes, english not my native language

Comment: instead '#devQty'+i in example '#qty'+i

Comment: change Array to Object, var out = {}

Comment: You getting a non existing item of an array (undefined) and trying to add something. You need to check this before add check the answers :D

Comment: Thx to all! i changed array to object, It`s working now, but when i try make console.log(out), i see [object Object], but if i make console.log(out['4941']) all is good.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a object `{}` like this example:

```
var out = {}; //change to a object 
var tot = jQuery('#totitems').val();

for(var i = 1; i <= tot; i++)
{
    //now you can acess like properties/hashmap
    out[jQuery('#productid'+i).val()] += parseFloat(jQuery('#devQty'+i).val());
}
```

You also need verify if is undefined before use `+=` like this:

```
var out = {}; //change to a object 
var tot = jQuery('#totitems').val();

for(var i = 1; i <= tot; i++)
{
    //now you can acess like properties/hashmap
   if(out[jQuery('#productid'+i).val()])
       out[jQuery('#productid'+i).val()] += parseFloat(jQuery('#devQty'+i).val());
   else
       out[jQuery('#productid'+i).val()] = parseFloat(jQuery('#devQty'+i).val());
}
```

You also have a little mistake using `#devQty` instead `#qty` and you need to parse the `tot` var:

```js
var out = {}; //change to a object 
var tot = parseInt(jQuery('#totitems').val());

for(var i = 1; i <= tot; i++)
{
   if(out[jQuery('#productid'+i).val()])
       out[jQuery('#productid'+i).val()] += parseFloat(jQuery('#qty'+i).val());
   else
       out[jQuery('#productid'+i).val()] = parseFloat(jQuery('#qty'+i).val());
}

console.log(out);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--For testing-->
<input type="hidden" name="totitems" id="totitems" value="3">


<input type="hidden" name="productid1" id="productid1" value="4941">
<input type="hidden" name="qty1" id="qty1" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="productid2" id="productid2" value="4942">
<input type="hidden" name="qty2" id="qty2" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="productid3" id="productid3" value="4941">
<input type="hidden" name="qty3" id="qty3" value="5">
```

This is another way to do this:

```js
var out = {}; 

jQuery("[name='product']").each(function(){

   var value = parseFloat(jQuery(this).val());
   var productID = jQuery(this).data("id");
   if(out[productID])
       out[productID] += value;
   else
       out[productID] = value;
});

console.log(out);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" name="product" data-id="4941" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="product" data-id="4942" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="product" data-id="4941" value="5">
```